# Comparing if two columns are equal in Where clauses

Tags: sql, database

I would like to compare if two columns are equal in the where clause. The columns are two columns are from different tables that have been joined

This is the statement that I am using

```
SELECT authors.state, sum(qty*price)as sales_revenue 
  from authors,titles, stores, sales 
 WHERE authors.state = (SELECT  stores.state from stores)
```

but I get an error that says this
M

```
sg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'authors.state' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: Just to note: there is cartesian product of titles + sales + (authors+titles). So the data returned by your query is meaningless.

Comment: Can you post your query as it stands now? Also, is qty and price defined in more than one table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
WHERE authors.state = stores.state
```

Or better, use the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax.

```
SELECT authors.state, sum(qty*price) as sales_revenue
FROM authors
JOIN stores ON authors.state = stores.state
JOIN titles ON ...
JOIN sales ON ...
GROUP BY authors.state
```

Comment: @Steffan Harris: Try adding the missing ON and GROUP BY.

Comment: @Steffan When using an aggregate function in the `SELECT` list, you need to add a `GROUP BY` clause. In this case, it would be `GROUP BY authors.state`

Comment: I did that and got these errors     Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "authors.state" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "authors.state" could not be bound.
Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The objects "sales" and "sales" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Can you paste your SQL?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
SELECT a.state,
       sum(l.qty*l.price)as sales_revenue 
       FROM authors a
       LEFT JOIN stores s on a.state=s.state
       GROUP BY a.state
```

Specify what columns are available in each table so you can check its relationships

e.g

```
authors = id,state
store = id,store
```

Regards